# SAP .NET Connector

Tags: .net, sap-dotnet-connector

I've been asked to work with the SAP .NET Connector. I currently use .NET 4.0 and VS2010. Is there anything I'm going to need to downgrade?

Also, does anyone know of any current tutorials online about how to use it? All I have is the information from SAP which isn't the most intuitive ever.

Comment: This question would be a lot more informative if you linked to the SAP .NET Connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a VS 2010 project added a new reference to the dll that provides the NCO 3.0 which are named as "sapnco.dll" and "sapnco_utils.dll." In Solution Explorer project and seek our References-> Add Reference ... Browse and search for the dll at: C: \ Program Files \ SAP \ SAP_DotNetConnector3.
After that we can use the classes and the NCO 3.0 and use in our project to make call to RFC, BAPIs and other features offered by this connector.

https://websmp210.sap-ag.de/~sapidb/011000358700000769232010D/NCo_30_Overview.pdf

https://websmp210.sap-ag.de/~sapidb/011000358700000769232010D/NCo_30_ProgrammingGuide.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Using the SAP.NET Connector to Connect your .NET Applications to SAP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/SAP_NET_Connector.aspx).
You can also try [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/3/7/f371bbba-2341-41bf-822d-2c7dd4174756/UI_CreateWebServices_5min.ppt)